# Where did the 'M' go?

Tags: java

I played a bit around with String Buffer and noticed, that mixing chars and String is a bad idea. I expected my following code to print "Main", however just got an "ain".

Clearly word was initialized with the char version of the String Buffer constructor, however I tested several methods like toString or getIndex( ), but could not find anything beside "ain" - which makes me wonder: What did the constructor do? Is there a usage for it? Can the 'M' somehow be retrieved again from word ?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class OrNotPublicClass {
    private static Random rnd = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer word = null;
        switch (rnd.nextInt(2)) {
        case 1:
            word = new StringBuffer('P');
        case 2:
            word = new StringBuffer('G');
        default:
            word = new StringBuffer('M');
        }
        word.append("ain");
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forget to `break` in your first two switch statements...

Comment: Use debugger in those situations.

Comment: No `"Gain"` for you! (read doc of `nextInt(...)` to understand why; pay special attention to words "inclusive" and "exclusive").

Comment: Do NOT use `StringBuffer`. Most of the times, you'll want the faster version `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @fge, why do you think I forgot it? I was simply interested in StringBuffer +  what happens, if you mix Strings and chars

Comment: Because like that you will always execute `word = new StringBuffer(' M');`.

Comment: So many errors in so few lines. You should really learn Java deeper.

Comment: @ctst, does this pose any problem for this code?

Comment: Well, unless you don't want the words "Pain" or "Gain" and don't care for superfluous code (the two cases) it doesn't pose a problem :-)

Comment: Exactly this was the case here :), but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apart from the `break` problem, the main problem here is how you initialize your `StringBuffer`.

There is no constructor accepting a `char` as an argument, [but there is one accepting an `int` for the capacity](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#StringBuffer-int-).

And that is the one you use...

You should do:

```
word = new StringBuilder(); // not StringBuffer
// switch. Then:
word.append("ain");
```

(also note the use of `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`; the latter is useful only in the rare case where thread-safety is required)

Comment: That is the real problem.

Comment: @fge, oh so that's what happened. I guess I have then to check what CharSequence does. 
There is also the constructor: StringBuffer(CharSequence seq)
however I have never used it before..

Comment: @bauerschluessel A `CharSequence` is an interface, and `String` implements it. As such, this means that this constructor is the one you'll ultimately use. You should always have a tab open to the JDK javadoc somewhere :p

Comment: `StringBuffer` is NOT deprecated... It's the threadsafe version of `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire yeah, and when exactly do you need that anyway? I have never, ever seen a legitimate situation where this was needed

Comment: @fge Who cares? You can consider it's deprecated if you want and you can say "I consider it deprecated", just don't say "it's deprecated" because at the end of the day, the Javadoc is right.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, do you say "The Javadoc is right" or do you think "The Javadoc is right"? Where is the difference to fge's comment?

Comment: @blauerschluessel the javadoc is the API definition. It's what everybody bases their code on. So if you go that way, be prepared. Also, I think (totally arbitrary) that more people refer to the Javadoc than to fge's comments.

Comment: Great catch, @fge. For the StringBuffer/StringBuilder conundrum, I was told that in the uncontended case (as it would be here, since `word` is a local variable), the performance difference is negligible.

Comment: @blauerschluessel, use of a good IDE (and paying attention to its hints) helps. See how IDEA helps [here](http://imgur.com/8oftyp0)!

Answer (score 13):

The issue with your code is pretty simple:
`new StringBuffer('M')` doesn't do what you think it does. There exists no constructor for `StringBuffer` that expects a `char`. Instead this constructor is called: `StringBuffer(int capacity)`, with `char` being implicitly converted to `int`.

So basically your code doesn't create a new `StringBuffer` containing a single character, but a `StringBuffer` with the capacity matching the given character.

But there are aswell some other issues, like missing `break` at the end of each `case`, so after the switch-statement, `word` will always be `new StringBuffer('M');`

The reason why this compiles is primitive widening conversion. Basically any integral data-type can be converted into another integral data-type, as long as the conversion is loss-less. Here are some links for further reading:
[StringBuffer docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)
[Primitive Widening - JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

Answer (score 3):

It used `StringBuffer`'s `int` constructor which sets the initial buffer's capacity.

Why did it use the int constructor? It has to do with [Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no StringBuffer constructor that accepts a char. What happens here is that Java has made a [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) to transform the `char` into an `int` and then a `StringBuffer` with initial capacity of `77` was created.

But, there is a constructor that accepts a `String` and you can use it to solve your problem:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("M");
```

Anyway, it is also recommended that you use `StringBuilder`, which is designed to be faster drop-in replacement for `StringBuffer` in places where the string buffer was being used by a single thread.